# Errors after Updating Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I just Updated `Android studio` to `3.0` and there some errors :

> Error:failed linking file resources.
>   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>
> Error:'' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
>
> Error:error: '' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
>   C:\Users\orshk\OneDrive\MyButton2\MyButton2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>   Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED in 3s
>
> Information:7 errors
>
> Information:0 warnings
>
> Information:See complete output in console

Thank you!

Comment: can you add your gradle and activity_main!

Answer (score 0):

As it is quite obvious you have provided a **""** value of **android:background** attribute at some place inside activity_main.xml. Look for it and give it the appropriate value.